# how to define triggers in style in user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I have a user control and in it I have several textbox/ calendar/... controls which they all should be enabled or disabled based on a properety in my user control (IsEditing)

I created a dependency property IsEditing in my user control and now I want to define a style that all of the controls use it to became enabled or disabled.

I am trying to do something such as this:

```
<ad:DocumentContent.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ReadOnlyMode">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ad:DocumentContent.Resources>
```

But I am getting this error: Property 'IsEditing' was not found in type 'FrameworkElement'.

How can I address the correct property for triggers?

---

Update 1:

I defined the IsEditing as follow:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsEditing", typeof(Boolean), typeof(MyDetailDataControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

And defined styles as follow:

```
<ad:DocumentContent.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ReadOnlyMode" xmlns:u="clr-namespace:MyProject.Controls" TargetType="{x:Type u:MyDetailDataControl}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ad:DocumentContent.Resources>
```

But I am getting the following error now: 
Property 'IsEditing' was not found in type 'MyDetailDataControl'.

I think there is a problem with the dependency property definition.

---

Update 2:

I changed the xaml as follow (add  xmlns:l="clr-namespace:MyProject.Controls" at the user control section so the namespace became available everywhere) and also used the method which is define here http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-debug-triggers-using-trigger.html to debug the trigger)

```
<ad:DocumentContent.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ReadOnlyMode" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger my:TriggerTracing.TriggerName="BoldWhenMouseIsOver" my:TriggerTracing.TraceEnabled="True" Property="l:MyDetailDataControl.IsEditing" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ad:DocumentContent.Resources>
```

But the trigger is not fired? Do you I need implement notify property mechanism? if yes, how can I do this? Is there any special technique for implementing property change notification when the property is an attached property?

---

Update 3:
Changed to this version, which is not related to my own IsEditing property. But still doesn't work.

```
<ad:DocumentContent.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type l:MyDetailDataControl}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger my:TriggerTracing.TriggerName="BoldWhenMouseIsOver" my:TriggerTracing.TraceEnabled="True" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ad:DocumentContent.Resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the [`TargetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) of the style to the type of your UserControl. Or you prefix all the properties with it.

```
<!-- Using TargetType -->
<Style xmlns:u="clr-namespace:Test.UserControls"
       x:Key="ReadOnlyMode"
       TargetType="{x:Type u:MyUserControl1}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="True">
            <!-- ... -->
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<!-- Using qualified property -->
<Style xmlns:u="clr-namespace:Test.UserControls"
       x:Key="ReadOnlyMode">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="u:MyUserControl1.IsEditing" Value="True">
            <!-- ... -->
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

Regarding your other problem: The property needs a CLR-Wrapper:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsEditing", typeof(Boolean), typeof(MyDetailDataControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
// This:
public Boolean IsEditing
{
    get { return (Boolean)GetValue(IsEditingProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsEditingProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: If I use the arget type as TextBox, it doesn't solve the problem and I am getting this error: Property 'IsEditing' was not found in type 'TextBox'.

Comment: See my edits, i said the type of your UserControl, not its base class.

Comment: There are two style and two trigger. should I use both of them or one is enough?

Comment: @user, choose one of them. They both do the same, just with different syntax.

Comment: @user: Those are the two different methods you can use. If you address more than one custom property i'd suggest using the first method. (Actually i would suggest that either way)

Comment: I did this and have a new problem. see my original question which I edited with what I changed.

Comment: @user654019: Gawd... You are not supposed to specify some totally wrong TargetType and use prefixes at the same time, if you do that the property will be interpreted as an attached property for TextBoxes, **which it is not**.

Comment: I can see what you are saying but I can not fix it. I am going to post all of my xamel to make sure that I am not missing anything.

Comment: @user654019: Do yourself a favour and read some documentation: [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx), [`Trigger.Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.property.aspx)

Comment: @user654019: Just change the TargetType to your UserControl's type and remove the prefixes in the `Property` value. I do not have time for this. You are trying to style the UserControl, so the TargetType should be jsut that. There is absolutely nothing hard about this.

Comment: I did but without any sucess!

Comment: @user654019: Do you even apply the style anywhere?

Comment: I found the problem: I subclassed my control from AvalonDock DocumentConent class and by some reason it stops all the trigers. I made it to be based on UserControl and it is somehow working. Need to spend more time on it .